# How do I set the exit code of a one line command to 1 if the result if blank?

Tags: bash, exit-code

If have a command, say `echo ""`, and I want the exit code of that to be `1`, however if I were to run the command `echo "foo"` I would want the status code to be `0`.

Comment: Why do you want to modify the exit-code of built-in utilities? I suspect this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is the real problem?

Comment: Define blank. `echo ""` prints one newline character. After `result=$(echo "")` the variable holds an empty string because `$()` removes all trailing newline characters. Superficial answers that capture the result this way and then `echo "$result"` convert zero or more trailing newline characters to exactly one, unless they explicitly compensate somehow.

Comment: Piping to `ifne -n false` will generate exit status `1` for empty input, `0` otherwise (unless there is something wrong with `ifne` itself). This is not an answer because "blank" seems not to be equivalent to "empty" in the context of the question. The output of `echo ""` is not empty. `echo "" | ifne -n false` exits with `0`, `echo -n "" | ifne -n false` exits with `1`.

Comment: My guess is that the real problem is how to test for an empty string in bash.

Comment: I've used `whatevercommand | grep .` for similar purposes before (the `grep` will exit with success if it sees at least one non-blank line, but it also suppresses blank lines from the output). But I whether this'd work for you without more information. What are you actually trying to achieve here?

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a function for that:

```bsh
notblank() {
    local result
    result=$( "$@" )     # execute the command and capture the output
    echo "$result"
    [[ -n "$result" ]]
}
```

Then:

```bsh
$ notblank echo "hello"; echo $?
hello
0

$ notblank echo "$noSuchVariable"; echo $?

1
```

specifically for echo:

```bsh
myecho() { echo "$*"; [[ -n "$*" ]]; }
```

or even

```bsh
echo() {
    builtin echo "$*"
    [[ -n "$*" ]]
}
```

but `echo -n "some string"` will not respect the `-n` option. That can be worked around, but at the cost of more complexity:

```bsh
echo () {
    local opt OPTIND OPTARGS
    local echo_opts=()
    while getopts :neE opt; do
        case $opt in
            [neE]) echo_opts+=("-$opt") ;;
            ?)  echo "invalid option: -$OPTARG" >&2
                return 1
                ;;
        esac
    done
    shift $((OPTIND - 1))

    builtin echo "${echo_opts[@]}" "$*"
    [[ -n "$*" ]]
}
```

Comment: Is there anyway to do this as a single line?

Comment: No. You need to capture the text, print it _then_ test it.

Comment: Could this work then? `result=$(echo ""); [[ -n "$result" ]]`? (for the question, the use of echo is just a placeholder for an actual command that run and could output either blank or not.)

Comment: Then you're missing the actual output on stdout: `result=$(echo ""); echo "$result"; [[ -n "$result" ]]`